# Хранимая функция PosgreSQL на С

Tags: c, postgresql

Я осваиваю написание хранимых функций на с для PostgreSQL. Я успешно скомпилировал и запустил простенькую функцию. Но дальше я столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Я хочу получить строку из таблицы и дальше считать свое значение. Но проблема в том что линковщик выдает ошибку и я не понимаю почему. 

Подскажите как исправить эту проблему.
   
gcc -IC:\PROGRA~1\PostgreSQL\10\include\server\port\win32^
   
 -IC:\PROGRA~1\PostgreSQL\10\include\server ^
   
 -IC:\PROGRA~1\PostgreSQL\10\include ^
   
 -IC:\PROGRA~1\PostgreSQL\10\include\server\executor ^
   
 -shared -o test.dll test.c -DHAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64
   
 **C:\Users\D899~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccj4rNqW.o:test.c:(.text+0x75): undefined reference to 'pg_detoast_datum'
   
 C:\Users\D899~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccj4rNqW.o:test.c:(.text+0x93): undefined reference to `GetAttributeByName'
   
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос минимальный пример кода: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Мелкий https://pastebin.com/f9eiyiY3

Comment: Вот обсуждение [такой же проблемы](https://postgrespro.ru/list/id/20050426003615.DDB5D56449@svr1.postgresql.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно с библиотекой postgres.lib слинковать

```
gcc -I%PATH_TO_POSTGRES_DIR%\include\server\port\win32 ^
    -I%PATH_TO_POSTGRES_DIR%\include\server ^
    -I%PATH_TO_POSTGRES_DIR%\include ^
    -L%PATH_TO_POSTGRES_DIR%\lib ^
    -shared -o hello.dll hello.c -DHAVE_LONG_LONG_INT_64 -lpostgres
```